# Немного об исключениях в языке программирования Java

Tags: java, исключения, переменные, обработка-ошибок, обработка

Возникло буквально 2 вопроса, которые прямо или косвенно, но всё-таки имеют отношение к механизму исключительных ситуаций в языке программирования *Java*.

Все мы знаем о таком ключевом слове, как `throws`, которое является частью контракта и обязывает вызывающий метод обрабатывать те типы исключений, которые перечислены после этого слова в вызываемом методе. То есть, если говорить немного иными словами, мы имеем дело с механизмом, который позволяет нам делегировать обработку исключений на уровень выше. В этой связи возникают следующие вопросы. Если данное объявление встречается в методе `main(String[] args)`, то кому передаётся обязательство на обработку всех потенциальных исключительных ситуаций, типы которых были перечислены после ключевого слова `throws`? Правильно ли я понимаю, что выше метода `main(String[] args)` в данной иерархии находится только сама *JVM*? И если мы делегируем обработку исключений именно *JVM*, то каким образом она подходит к этому вопросу? На практике у нас выскочит необработанное исключение с трассировкой стека на консоли. Значит ли это, что *JVM* никак не обрабатывает исключение, если оно таки доходит до самой виртуальной машины?

Это был первый интересующий меня момент, а теперь второй момент. Рассмотрим поближе конструкцию *try-catch-finally*. Я не стану описывать все особенности данной конструкции, а лишь укажу одну вещь, которая меня больше всего интересует на текущий момент. Возьмём такой код:

```
int someMethod() {
    try{
        /* Some code, that provokes an exception */ 
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        return 5;     
    } finally {
        return 10; 
    }    
}
```

Видим интересную конструкцию, в которой мы последовательно выполняем оператор `return` целых 2 раза. Очевидно, что метод возвратит в место вызова целочисленное значение 10, но интересует меня немного не это. Меня интересует, куда именно помещается значение, которое является операндом для оператора `return`? Ведь наше возвращаемое значение проходит через процесс переприсваивания, значит ли это, что оно изначально хранится в какой-то временной переменной? Если честно, то никогда раньше об этом не задумывался, а сейчас сижу и ломаю себе голову в поисках ответа на этот вопрос. Буду всем крайне благодарен за помощь!

Comment: На второй случай декомпиляция показала просто `return 10;`. И вообще, IDEA выделяет такие ситуации, намекая, что не надо так запутывать код. Я когда-то задумался что будет при выполнении `return i++;` - куда девается увеличенное значение и вообще вычисляется оно или игнорится - ответ  нашел так же, декомпиляцией `class` файла.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Поделитесь своим опытом? Куда же девается изначение при операции `return i++`?

Comment: Метод `static int someMethod2() {
        int i = 0;
        return i++;
    }` в результате декомпиляции преобразован в `static int someMethod2() {
        int i = 0;
        byte var10000 = i;
        int var1 = i + 1;
        return var10000;
    }`. Как видим, `var1` нигде больше не используется

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець А какой декомпилятор использовали?

Comment: Да просто открыл `class` файл ИДЕЕЙ

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Действительно, сделал также и получил Ваш код. Никогда не приходило в голову писать подобные вещи. Теперь буду знать, что нет никакого смысла возвращать результат операции инткрементирования/декрементирования.

Comment: Это касается только ПОСТ-ин(де)кремента. `return ++i;` очень даже имеет смысл!

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Точно! Суть уловил, спасибо! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что выше метода main(String[] args) в данной иерархии находится только сама JVM?

да, где то так.

> И если мы делегируем обработку исключений именно JVM, то каким образом она подходит к этому вопросу?

это уже не делегирование:) это "мне все равно, делай что хочешь".

> Значит ли это, что JVM никак не обрабатывает исключение, если оно таки доходит до самой виртуальной машины?

jvm это и есть виртуальная машина. И в этом свете предложение выглядит странно:).

Да, если исключение вышло за пределы программы, то оно попадает к jvm. Она это дело залогирует (покажет стектрейс) и остановит выполнение программы. А что ей ещё делать? Пытаться угадать логику программы?

> Видим интересную конструкцию, в которой мы последовательно выполняем оператор return целых 2 раза.

да, это на первый взгляд странная ситуация и хороший вопрос на собеседование - выходит ли return c метода.

Но jvm гарантирует выполнение finally блока и она в него переходит. Но что бы решить дилему, можете считать, что есть некая переменная, где хранится результат выполнения (и в паскале эта переменная имя Result или имя функции, в c/c++ это обычно регистр eax). А return просто запоминает этот результат и делает выход с метода с выполнением нужных finally блоков.

По моему наблюдению, это одна с самых трудных для понимания вещей начинающими java программистами. Но даже и матерые программисты иногда задумываются.

Comment: Логику я сразу уловил, просто не мог понять, где и как она хранится. Сам `return`, именно в качестве оператора безусловного перехода всегда срабатывает именно в блоке finally, если он там имеется. Хотя... А если после блока *try-catch-finally* находится ещё один `return`, то сработает уже он? :)

Comment: А зачем коду после finally выполняться, если только это не другой finally блок?

Comment: Да, Вы правы из-за использования оператора `return` мы просто получим "*Error:(x, x) java: unreachable statement*", если попытаемся засунуть ещё один `return` после блока `finally`.

Comment: java  в этом плане немного интересна - не даст даже скомпилить код, который не совсем корректный

Comment: Окей, то есть у нас получается примерно следующий процесс. Сначала мы попадаем в блок `catch` и там сталкиваемся с оператором `return`, он "запоминает" результат и помещает его в "некую переменную" (?), а потом, когда мы уже попадаем в блок `finally`, то значение этой переменной перезаписывается и возвращается при помощи того же `return` в место вызова. Верно?

Comment: да, где то так. Хотя мне лично try-catch блок легче представлять в виде такой себе отдельной функции. В этом случае два return значительно легче воспринимаются.

Comment: Та вроде бы и так нормально воспринимается. Сделал декомпиляцию class-файла и получил такой вот результат:     `public static int someMethod() {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception var5) {
            boolean var1 = true;
            return 10;
        } finally {
            ;
        }
    }` Означает ли это что у нас выполняется всё-таки лишь один `return`, как видно из кода?

Comment: И да, если кому-то нужно для собеседования, то придумал такой вот пример. Что самое интересное, данный код полностью рабочий! Здесь целых 4 оператора return в одном фрейме:     `public static int someMethod() {
        boolean b = true;
        if(b) {
            try {
                if(b)
                    throw new Exception();
                return 1;    
            } catch(Exception e) {
                return 2;
            } finally {
                return 3;
            }
        }
        return 4;
    }`